# writeToDB function executes only once

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code implemented with node.js, i wonder why writeToDB is getting called but data is not inserted in the DB after first time.

```
uploadInfoObject = {
    ProcessId: pid,
    Type: "type",
    ModifiedDate: new Date(),
    Status: "Started",
    Message: "Processing Started"
};
writeToDB(uploadInfoObject);
console.log('File Downloaded! ' + data.ContentType);
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;
child = exec('gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -dTextAlphaBits=4 -r300 -o /tmp/%d.jpeg ' + stored_pdf, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    uploadInfoObject = {
        ProcessId: Processid,
        Type: "Ticket",
        ModifiedDate: new Date(),
        Status: "Processing",
        Message: "Splitting into pages done"
    }
    writeToDB(uploadInfoObject); //this gets called  but data is not there in the db
});
```

writeToDB Funciton

```
function writeToDB(infoObject) {
    dbService.connectDb(config.DB_CONFIG.CONNECTIONSTRING, {})
    .then(() => {
        return dbService.insert(infoModel(dbService), infoObject);
    })
    .then(data => dbService.disconnectDb(data))
    .then(data => console.log("success"))
    .catch((error) => {
        dbService.disconnectDb(error).then(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    });
}
```

Please help

Comment: your code isn't very easy to read - have you thought about proper indenting?

Comment: `writeToDB` is asynchronous - I'm guessing that's an issue

Comment: @JaromandaX i did the indentation

Comment: how can i wait and then execute next, since i have to use the method in most places. can you show a sample

Comment: return the promise from `writeToDB` - and use `writeToDB(uploadInfoObject).then( ... rest of code in function goes here like any other .then chain)`

Comment: `i did the indentation` - why is `var exec` indented by 40 characters compared to `console.log('File Downloaded! ' + data.ContentType);` - I'd expect both of those to be on the same "level" of indentation

Comment: writeToDB already returning the promise right? ok thanks i will try that. can you post as answer, i wil mark it

Comment: `writeToDB already returning the promise right?` - wrong, as you don't actually `return` from `writeToDB`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138581/discussion-between-face-turn-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: can you post a sample , i will follow that please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, return a Promise from writeToDB, and then wrap the code after `writeToDB(uploadInfoObject)` in a .then, like so

```
uploadInfoObject = {
    ProcessId: Processid,
    Type: "Ticket",
    ModifiedDate: new Date(),
    Status: "Started",
    Message: "Processing Started"
};
writeToDB(uploadInfoObject)
// wrap in .then
.then(() => {
    console.log('File Downloaded! ' + data.ContentType);
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec('gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -dTextAlphaBits=4 -r300 -o /tmp/%d.jpeg ' + stored_pdf, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        uploadInfoObject = {
            ProcessId: Processid,
            Type: "Ticket",
            ModifiedDate: new Date(),
            Status: "Processing",
            Message: "Splitting into pages done"
        }
        writeToDB(uploadInfoObject); //this gets called  but data is not there in the db
    });
});
function writeToDB(infoObject) {
    // add return so a promise is returned
    return dbService.connectDb(config.DB_CONFIG.CONNECTIONSTRING, {})
    .then(() => dbService.insert(infoModel(dbService), infoObject))
    .then(data => dbService.disconnectDb(data))
    .then(data => console.log("success"))
    .catch((error) => {
        dbService.disconnectDb(error).then(() => {
            // throw the original error, otherwise .then will be called!
            throw error;
        })
    });
}
```

Note: your writeToDB function has a flaw in that it catches the error, but then deals with it - any code calling the function would proceed with `.then` regardless - hence the throw in the disconnect .then callback

Comment: thanks a lot, one quick question, if i use the same method again and again, should i use then and add the rest of code inside it?

Comment: that's how asynchronous code has to be used ... oh, and I made a change to writeToDB catch - explained in the answer